# Syntax error ',' expected in Razor ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to use tagHelper in my practice project but when I run the app I get the error [image: here] in image, I'm new to MVC.

ContactViewModel:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(4096, MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Contact.cshtml:

```
 @model WebApplication1.ViewModels.ContactViewModel;
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

@section scripts {
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
<h1>Contact Me</h1>

<form>
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input  asp-for="Name"/>
    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
    <input  asp-for="Email"/>
    <label asp-for="Message"></label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="4" asp-for="Message"></textarea>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.ContactViewModel;`

with

`@model WebApplication1.ViewModels.ContactViewModel`

Comment: thank u very much @serhiyb.... u made my day...